# Improve query performance - SELECT and SUM from two table

Tags: mysql, sql

**What I have :**  (explain)
I Working with FreeRadius a radius server and I want to calculate today users total traffic used .
I have a table named as `users` , and second table is `users_graph` .

`users_graph` table collect bandwidth data for each 15minutes (96 row per day for each user) .

I try to make a query to collect users with a specified groupname and SUM of total traffic used today .

**What I do :**
I make below SQL query and test for a result , test with 20 user and 80 row on users_graph for each user .

Result : execute time of my query is about 3 seconds.

**What I want :**
I try to improve my query to give more performance and fastest execute time .
Is there a way to improve below query ?

**MyQuery :**

```
SELECT 
  u.`UserName`,
  SUM(g.`Total`) totaltime 
FROM
  users u
  INNER  JOIN `users_graph` g
    ON g.`UserName` = u.`UserName`
WHERE u.`GroupName` = 'Festival'  AND g.`Time` > '1408995000'
GROUP BY u.`UserName`;
```

Samle Resut :

```
UserName   GroupName    totaltime  
---------  -----------  ----------
test123    Festival      81
test332    Festival      19
test523    Festival      29
```

*EDIT:*

**Tables info :**

```
/*Table: users_graph*/
----------------------

/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field     Type          Collation          Null    Key     Default  Extra           
--------  ------------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  
Guid      bigint(22)    (NULL)             NO      MUL     (NULL)   auto_increment  
Time      int(11)       (NULL)             YES             0                        
UserName  varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   
Down      int(11)       (NULL)             YES             0                        
Up        int(11)       (NULL)             YES             0                        
Total     int(11)       (NULL)             YES             0                        

/*Index Information*/
---------------------

Table        Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  
-----------  ----------  --------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  
users_graph           1  Guid                 1  Guid         A              5584276    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE       

/*DDL Information*/
-------------------

CREATE TABLE `users_graph` (
  `Guid` bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Time` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `UserName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Down` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Up` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Total` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `Guid` (`Guid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5584277 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

/*Table: users*/
----------------

/*Index Information*/
---------------------

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  
------  ----------  ----------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  
users            0  PRIMARY                1  id           A                21250    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE       
users            0  UserName               1  UserName     A                21250    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE          

/*DDL Information*/
-------------------

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`UserName` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Pass` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`GroupName` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27456 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Although some implicit conversion may occur, note that '1408995000' is a string. 1408995000 is an integer

Comment: Thanks Strawberry , but I tested it now , but now affect on execute time (still have about 3seconds)

Comment: OK, for help with performance we really need to see proper DDLs *and* the EXPLAIN - although I suppose I'd start with a compound index on (u.UserName,u.GroupName) as well as an index on time [or g.username,g.time)?]

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you , I added the table info /DDL .

Comment: great, and the EXPLAIN ?

Comment: A combined index on `u.GroupName` and `u.UserName` will probably help. In addition, you might try to add an index on Time.

Comment: Is there an echo on this line? ;-)

Comment: Why does users_graph store the username if the user's id is PRIMARY !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks , Now execute time reduced to about 1 second. users_graph made from a different program and can't access to database directly .

Comment: @Strawberry , please add a answer to accept it :) .

Comment: Hello @Root125 do you mind sharing with me the code you used to populate the graph table?

I am currently running a radius server and having some brain block trying to figure out how to extract useful stats and information from my radius tables.

my contact details are on my website (not putting my email here in case of spiders and stuff) https://erikthiart.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must index searched columns , for example if I want to search where `time` greater than equal , I must index column of `time` then , Mysql sort `time` row .

indexed columns can retrieve faster result .